# Filter Report2, based on drilldown value on Report1

Tags: syntax, business-objects

I have a single Business Objects report with 2 tabs, Report1 and Report2.

I am trying to create a hyper link from Report1, so that when clicked it opens Report2 and filters to show the 'Status' value that was clicked.

The below link opens Report2 ok, but does not filter based on the status clicked in Report1

```
http://boshr.xxxxx.net/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp?iDocID=122706849&sType=wid&sReportName=Report2&sRefresh=Y&sWindow=Same&Request Status (SR)=([Request Status (SR)])
```

Please could somebody help mw with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the manual regarding OpenDocument functionality (e.g. *Viewing Documents Using OpenDocument*) on [help.sap.com](http://help.sap.com) for a full reference on the OpenDocument parameters. Make sure to download a manual that corresponds to the version of BusinessObjects you're using, as the available parameters tend to differ from version to version.

Also, make sure that you've [encoded your URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), otherwise it won't work. If you're using Web Intelligence, the function `UrlEncode()` will do this for you.

One last tip: if you're using the (D)HTML viewer for Web Intelligence (or *Interactive Viewer* as it's called in some versions), you can use it to construct the URL for you through a GUI. Have a look at the tutorial "[Create a link between documents (DHTML client)](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-21161)" for more information.